# OCaml: Matching with any negative

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, negative-number

Is there a way to get pattern matching to match my value with any negative number? It does not matter what the negative number is I just need to match with any negative.

I have accomplished what I want with this simple code:

```
let y = if(n < 0) then 0 else n in   
match y with  
0 -> []  
| _ -> [x] @ clone x (n - 1)
```

But I want to eliminate that `if` statement and just get it to check it as another case in the `match` statement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use a guard:

```
match n with
    _ when n < 0 -> []
  | _ -> [x] @ clone x (n - 1)
```

Comment: Oh I see, I will have to go do some research on guards. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can make your code a little cleaner like this:

```
match n < 0 with
| true -> []
| false -> [x] @ clone x (n - 1)
```

Even better would be:

```
if n < 0 then [] else [x] @ clone x (n - 1)
```

Generally, if statements are clearer than matches for simple logical tests.

While we're at it, we might as well use `::` in place of `@`:

```
if n < 0 then [] else x :: clone x (n - 1)
```

Comment: But while we're doing all this, we also introduce a bug where `n = 0` is mapped to `0 :: clone x (-1)` instead of `[]`. It's generally better to try to answer the question, as in Chuck's answer, both to avoid this and in case the real situation is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is the keyword when. By head (I can't test right now)

let y = match n with
| when n < 0 -> 0
| 0 -> []
| _ -> [x] @ clone x (n - 1)

However, even your example shouldn't work. As on one side you return an int, and on the other a list.

Comment: No, both paths in the match are lists. The `@` operator has the type `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my code, the if statement is just an additional line of code to set the value for the match statement for when n is less than 0. It's just supposed to do the same thing as the 0 case and return an empty list.

Comment: Oh indeed! It was way too late for me to answer on SO yesterday...
My bad :/